# Networkx Dijkstra Shortest Path exists but is way too long - algorithm that gives me an approximation upfront

Tags: networkx, shortest-path

I am computing a shortest path with networkx. Works fine most of the time, but sometimes the nodes are connected, but over a really weird very remote connection in the network. In this case the algorithm produces a memory error. My question is, if there is a nice way to check upfront if the connection between the nodes will make sense for a shortest path in terms of length, by a threshold which I define.

Comment: Are there only specific pairs you are trying to find the shortest path between (in which case consider `bidirectional_dijkstra` which will use significantly less memory and run faster)?  Or are you looking at all pairs (in which case, consider `all_pairs_dijkstra_path` which has an optional cutoff argument)?

Comment: There's a few approximation algorithms listed here https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/11866/8532

Comment: @Joel the cutoff actually helped me. I used it like this: graphcost, shortestpath = nx.single_source_dijkstra(graph, source, target, cutoff) . If you post this as an answer, I can accept it

Comment: Do you know that all your nodes are reachable? (Or your source and target always are in the same connected component) Then you could pre-calculate some landmarks and the distance between these landmarks. With this recalculated distances, you could get an estimation based on the triangle inequality.

Comment: yes they are reachable. I computed Islands and I only do the shortest path operation if they are on the same island. The cutoff option however works well for my case

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in general solution you can modify Dijkstras algorithm and limit it to a maximum number of nodes or a maximum length and just abort, once that threshold is broken.

I don't know networkx so I don't know if this is available out of the box.

Comment: that is actually a good hint. I checked, it is not available out of the box but the implementation seems not to be too much effort. I will wait however with marking this answer as right, maybe someone will come up with a more generic one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this algo:

```py
from networkx.algorithms import approximation as approx
approx.local_node_connectivity(G, source, target, cutoff=2)
```